# lattice: overlay density plot with parameters in histogram

Tags: r, lattice

The following four calls return what seems to be the exact same graph. How can I control the panel density plot? Thank you.

```
 library(lattice)
 df <- data.frame( y = runif(100) , p = rep(c('a','b'),50) )

 histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
      type = "density",
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.densityplot(x, ...)
      })


 histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
      type = "density",
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.densityplot(x, bw=100,kernel="gaussian",...)
      })

 histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
      type = "density",
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.densityplot(x, dargs=list(bw=100,kernel="gaussian"),...)
      })

 histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
      type = "density", bw=100,kernel="gaussian" ,
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.densityplot(x, ...)
      })
```

Comment: Your third code block is almost right, but you made the mistake of writing `dargs` where you need to write `darg`.

Comment: Re. your first comment: this will work `df <- data.frame( y = runif(100) , p = rep(c('a','b'),50) )`. Re. your second comment, the graph stays the same, `dargs` or `darg` but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Take a closer look. When you set `bw=100`, the density gets so smoothed out it goes to close to zero everywhere. Set `bw=1` with the sample data you gave me, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I ran the bottom three graphs with bw=1 and there's no change in the plot. I cleared the plots area (RStudio), started again, no change. Which syntax did you use to observe the change ?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code below in my local R window, and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above, your third call to `histogram()` was very close. You just needed to write `darg` instead of `dargs`.

Here's an example to show that `darg` does indeed, as documented in `?panel.densityplot`, give you control over the smoothing parameters:

```
library(gridExtra)  ## For grid.arrange()
library(lattice)
df <- data.frame(y = runif(100) , p = rep(c('a','b'),50))

p1 <- histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
          type = "density",
          panel=function(x, ...) {
             panel.histogram(x, ...)
             panel.densityplot(x, darg=list(bw = 1, kernel="gaussian"),...)
      })

p2 <- histogram(~ y | p , data = df , 
          type = "density",
          panel=function(x, ...) {
              panel.histogram(x, ...)
              panel.densityplot(x, darg=list(bw = 0.2, kernel="gaussian"),...)
      })

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]